# Multiple threads waiting for nothing?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, spring-batch

TLDR : during a multithreaded massive database insertion, multiple thread are waiting for no evident reason.

We need to create multiple rows in a database. To speed up insertion, we use multithreading so that multiple objects can be generated and inserted in parallel. We are using Hibernate, Spring batch and Spring scheduling (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, Partitioner, ItemProcessor). We started from [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-partitioning-example/).

We looked at thread states with JVisualVM and noticed that **there are never more than 8 active threads at a time, whatever the hardware running the program**. We tried "standard desktop" computers (dual core), but also two AIX : one with 8 active CPU, one with 60 active CPUs.

[image]

Any idea why we can't have more than 8 working threads at a time?

A list of things we already checked:

- All threads have a work to do (Partitioner and ThreadPoolTaskExecutor are configured so that each thread has the same amount of data to insert in DB).
- We tried various commit-interval : 1, P where P is the size of the partition, N where N is the sum of all P (it should not be the cause of the problem, but commiting data seems to be the long part of the job while data generation is fast).
- 8 is not a default value of any object's parameter we use.

Comment: What are you using to access the database? Is there a limit on number of concurrent db connections?

Comment: We use Hibernate. I'll check the number of connections, good idea. However a limit on the number of connections should not cause N-8 thread to START after the first 8 thread complete. To me, all thread should start all together, and we should see contention/locking (shown in red on jvisualvm)

Comment: @Martin, I don't know about Hibernate, but if I provided you with a library that allowed at most 8 threads to call at one time, and you tried calling it from 10 threads, you would not see the two extra thread theads blocked by a mutex.  You would see them waiting inside a Semaphore.acquire() call.

Comment: Into how many tables are you inserting/updating? Are they locked in this process? Perhaps you have eight threads with connections with locks.

Comment: So yes, there was a limit on the number of db connections of... 8 :). Configuring the property initialSize and maxActive of the BasicDataSource bean to a value equal to the number of threads let all thread work together (do not loose time trying to set this via hibernate, it did not work)! However I am running into a new problem : a lot of thread contention on hibernate ID generator. I'll investigate and tell you why :) Thanks guys for the suggestions